Time between two DateTime written out in x days, y hours, z minutes and a seconds
I have a Streamer.bot program which uses C# and I have a counter that I can update if a certain death happens. I want to have a command for Twitch that gives info about the DateTime of last incident and how much time in days, hours, minutes and seconds has passed since then.
So far I managed to save the DateTime of last incident in a variable (DateTime). I also managed to get the difference, but the formatting is an issue.
DateTime lastDraw = CPH.GetGlobalVar<DateTime>("Hanged last", true);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string difference = Convert.ToString(now - lastDraw);

Time since last incident: 00:07:59.2038479 (This is the result when around 8 minutes have passed) of the string difference variable. So, looks like I almost got it?
The CPH thing is just the command to read the DateTime variable with the last incident in it.
And sorry, I'm a absolute noob in C#, I know.
Goal is that the message is: Time since last incident: x days, y hours, z minutes and a seconds.
Any ideas on how I could do this?

The TimeSpan struct, which is returned by now - lastDraw, provides Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds properties. To access those properties, first save now - lastDraw to a TimeSpan variable instead of passing the expression directly to Convert.ToString:
TimeSpan span = now - lastDraw;

Then you can access span's properties to construct your string:
string difference = $"{span.Days} days, {span.Hours} hours, {span.Minutes} minutes and {span.Seconds} seconds";

Alternatively, you could use a custom TimeSpan format string:
string difference = (now - lastDraw).ToString("d' days, 'h' hours, 'm' minutes and 's' seconds'");


To omit "0 days", you could use the ? : conditional operator.
With $"..." interpolated strings:
TimeSpan span = now - lastDraw;
string difference =
    (span.Days != 0 ? $"{span.Days} days, " : "") +
    $"{span.Hours} hours, {span.Minutes} minutes, {span.Seconds} seconds";

With custom TimeSpan format strings:
TimeSpan span = now - lastDraw;
string difference =
    (span.Days != 0 ? span.ToString("d' days, '") : "") +
    span.ToString("h' hours, 'm' minutes and 's' seconds'");


Nice, that helped a lot! Is it possible to hide the day feature if it is zero?

@StefanBraun Lookup the if statement and the ? : ternary operator

@StefanBraun: I updated my answer with a couple ways you could omit zero days.

When you subtract two DateTime values, you get a TimeSpan, which provides a ToString() method that will let you do this:
DateTime lastDraw = CPH.GetGlobalVar<DateTime>("Hanged last", true);
string difference = (DateTime.Now - lastDraw).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ffffffff")

Note timestamp format strings are picky about those \ characters in ways DateTime format strings are not.

(Acknowledging, there are already 2 answers using 'on-board' utils, only... )
I am not affiliated with it, but maybe this could be an alternative for you:
Fiddle
using System;
using Humanizer;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ts = DateTime.Parse("2024-12-25T00:00:00") - DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Humanize(5) + " till XMas!");
    }
}

Output

24 weeks, 6 days, 9 hours, 4 minutes, 18 seconds till XMas!

NuGet / Project is Humanizer => https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-timespan
Pro: This will automatically take care of proper pluralization:
Fiddle
1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, 1 second till XMas!
It's also quite configurable: This
Console.WriteLine(ts.Humanize(4, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Us"), Humanizer.Localisation.TimeUnit.Day,collectionSeparator: null) + " till XMas!");

will produce something like
174 days, 8 hours, 45 minutes, and 2 seconds till XMas!
